# mysql store muptiple alias for one person

Tags: python, mysql, database, web-services

One person have one name and multiple alias。 Person can index by name and alias. So I design two table store this relationship:   and . Like this:

```
<user table>

|user_id    | int
|name       | varchar



<alias table>

|user_id    | int
|alias      | varchar
```

Two table joined by user_id.  So one user can set multiple alias and can index by alias.  **But now we need add unique constraint. If user's name and each alias are same it is considered repeat！** So i think use one  table store like this:

```
<user table>

|user_id           | int
|name              | varchar
|sorted_alias_str  | varchar


ps:  sorted_alias_str store each alias which join by comma. like: 'name1,name2'
```

**with unique constraint (name, sorted_alias_str)**

but the number of user's alias is limit by 'sorted_alias_str' length.

is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure I'm completely understanding your question.  Are you wanting the ability to store a different number of aliases per user along with keeping them unique?  Maybe a `trigger`...

Comment: i mean i want store different number of aliases per user.  And unique constraint is :  (name, each of alias)

if new user's name is duplicate  but alias is different (number of alias or textual), it is acceptable. 

if new user's name and alias all is duplicate, it isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The unique constraint should be on the  (user_id, name). This prevents one person (user_id) from having the same alias multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with having a unique constraint, but it should be `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (user_id, alias)` on the `alias` table.  But I disagee with the `sorted_alias_str`.  This column will be a hassle to maintain, because it will have to be recomputed each time any user adds or drops an alias.  Instead, you can just use `GROUP_CONCAT` to obtain a CSV list of aliases for each user, e.g.

```
SELECT t1.user_id,
       t1.name,
       t2.aliases
FROM user t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(alias, 'NA') AS aliases
    FROM alias
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Comment: 'sorted_alias_str' is used for unique constrant.  **The demand is unique constrant must on (user_name, each_user_alias)**.

if new user's name is duplicate but alias is different (number of alias or each textual), it is acceptable. 

if new user's name and alias all is duplicate, it isn't acceptable

Comment: @xwl Sorry, typo in there, I meant what you said.  I was on a cell phone when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have already gives a single user multiple aliases. A composite unique constraint ensures one user will not have the same alias more than once.

```
<user table>

|user_id    | int (unique)
|name       | varchar

<alias table>

|user_id    | int (unique, also ref to user.user_id)
|alias      | varchar

unique constraint (user_id, alias)
```

Every UNIQUE constraint is also an index.

For even more structure, you can put all of your known aliases in one table.

```
<user table>

|user_id    | int (unique)
|name       | varchar

<user_alias table>

|user_id    | int (ref to user.user_id)
|alias_id   | int (ref to alias.alias_id)

unique constraint (user_id, alias_id)

<alias table>

|alias_id   | int (unique)
|alias      | varchar
```

Finally, if you acknowledge that a name is just a specially identified alias, you can add a bit more structure :

```
<user table>

|user_id    | int (unique)
|name       | int (ref to alias.alias_id)

<user_alias table>

|user_id    | int (ref to user.user_id)
|alias_id   | int (ref to alias.alias_id)

unique constraint (user_id, alias_id)

<alias table>

|alias_id   | int (unique)
|alias      | varchar
```

Comment: If the alias table is user editable, this is a more complex implementation. Correcting the spelling of one user's alias from 'John' to 'Jon' would require adding a new row of 'Jon' to alias and updating user_alias from the alias_id corresponding to 'John' to the new alias_id of the new spelling of 'Jon'.